# how Convert Activity to Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm going to implement code in the fragment.What changes should I make?. Please guide me on what to do.

Part of my code:

requestPermission code:

```
 private void requestPermission() {
    if 
 (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, 
    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Please allow this permission 
 in App Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] 
 {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 
   PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

checkPermission code:

```
private boolean checkPermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, 
  android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

onRequestPermissionsResult code:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String 
 permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == 
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted 
     Successfully! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied :( ", 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: A `Fragment` does not inherit from an `Activity`. However you can check for permissions directly from a `v4.app.Fragment` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#requestpermissions & https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#onrequestpermissionsresult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line in top of frgment

```
public static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

requestPermission code:

```
    private void requestPermission() {
    if
    (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Please allow this permission in App Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]
                        {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

checkPermission code:

```
private boolean checkPermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()),
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

onRequestPermissionsResult code:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String
            permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission Granted Successfully! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission Denied :( ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```